# Can't read FITS file with GalSim

Tags: fits, galsim

**Setup**

- MacOS 10.12.6
- Python 2.7
- Galsim 1.4.4
- Numpy 1.13.1
- Astropy 1.3.3
- Fitsio

**Goal**

My goal is to take simulated wide field HST images (12288*12288 pixels, roughly 600MB in .fits format) and add the WFIRST detector features to it.

**Problem**

Unfortunately, I have faced difficulties reading the fits files.
The main question is how to turn fits images in the way that we can manipulate them by galsim.

**I've tried**

I have tried galsim fits method ‘galsim.fits.read(“fine_name.fits”)’ and I‘ve got :

```
galsim.Image(bounds=galsim.BoundsI(xmin=1, xmax=12288, ymin=1, ymax=12288), array=
    array([[ 0., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.],
[ 0., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.],
[ 0., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.],
...,
[ 0., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.],
[ 0., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.],
[ 0., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.]], dtype=float32), wcs=galsim.PixelScale(1.0))
```

I have tried `fitsio.read(“file_name.fits”)` as well but still, I am not able to convolve PSFs through 'galsim.Convolve' or add detector features.

-Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "I am not able to convolve..." etc.?  Do you get an error? What exact problem are you having?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you read the docstring for galsim.fits.read, you will see that it returns a galsim.Image, as you have found with your experiment.  To create a GSObject, you need to instantiate a galsim.InterpolatedImage, which will allow you to convolve and do other operations.  You can read the docstring for galsim.InterpolatedImage, and/or look at galsim demo11.py to see an example of this being done in practice (reading in an image file into an InterpolatedImage and convolving with something else).

Detector features *do* get added to images, not GSObjects.  For an example of this, see GalSim's demo13.py.

Questions of basic GalSim usage are covered in the Quick Reference Guide https://github.com/GalSim-developers/GalSim/blob/releases/1.4/doc/GalSim_Quick_Reference.pdf and the demos in the GalSim repository.